# How to consume external services in Dynamics 365 finance and operations

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I am new to MS Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations application development.

I am creating a D365 F&O application where i want to consume some services for this i have written a class library. I have followed below MS steps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/write-business-logic

I am trying to consume service in a X++ class .My code is simple,

Fullscreen

```
   public static void main(Args _args)
{
    // info(ServiceLibrary.StockQuoteClass::GetQuote("MSFT"));
    info(ServicesLib.DemoService::GetTeamName("TeamName"));
}
```

I am getting error at main that A Reference to System.Runtime Version=5 ,Culture=Neutral ,Public Key Token="dfsdfd" required to compile this module.

I have intalled .Net 5 latest sdk.restarted visual studio but not worked?

Answer (score 0):

- Add a reference pointing to the DriversLIcenseEvaluator project

From this part on, it explains very clear what to do before running. I think you haven't put in this reference the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the .NET framework version on your Class Library projetct to 4.6. D365 FnO runs on 4.6.